# how to get unique records on multiple column in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create message conversation list or message list same as Facebook or whatsapp, my records are saved in a message table like this.
[image]

Here m saving ToprofileId (user id) and FromProfileId (user id)
User 206 sends message to user 214 (message id 515), user 214 just reply to user 206(messageid 516).
message send by user 200 to 206 (messageid 517)
Another message sends by user 206 to 184 (messageid 517).
Now I want to display as conversations title. (user :214-206 or 206-214)as single row
Same as others if they also make conversation.

Suppose my user id is 206, then if m receive any message or send any message its should as single conversation .
[image]
Show last message in this conversation.

[image]

Remaining looks like as

The message list page looks like a Facebook page like
[image]

```
MsgID  |toId|fromID |isR|isF|isAl|Message|DateTime              |TargetUser
515    |214 |206    |1  |0  |0  |hiiii  |2013-12-26 12:19:51    |214
516    |206 |214    |0  |0  |0  |hello, |2013-12-26 12:21:44    |214
517    |206 |200    |1  |0  |0  |message|2013-12-26 12:22:59    |200
518    |184 |206    |0  |0  |0  |message|2013-12-26 14:52:30    |184
519    |200 |206    |0  |0  |0  |1a     |2013-12-26 16:11:58    |200
520    |200 |206    |0  |0  |0  |2b     |2013-12-26 16:12:02    |200
521    |200 |206    |0  |0  |0  |3a     |2013-12-26 16:12:04    |200
531    |200 |206    |1  |0  |0  |13     |2013-12-26 16:12:24    |200
532    |206 |200    |0  |0  |0  |14     |2013-12-26 16:12:34    |200
```

I have need all rows based on unique TargetUsers, result should be follow

```
MsgID  |toId|fromID |isR|isF|isAl|Message|DateTime              |TargetUser
516    |206 |214    |0  |0  |0  |hello, |2013-12-26 12:21:44    |214
517    |206 |200    |1  |0  |0  |message|2013-12-26 12:22:59    |200
518    |184 |206    |0  |0  |0  |message|2013-12-26 14:52:30    |184
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right then you want a SQL query to get all conversions for one user and its date to show it as the picture you give:

Do this query :

```
 Select FromProfileId, Message, DateTime
 From MessagingTable
 Where ToProfileId = 206
 And MessageId in ( Select Max(MessageId) From MessagingTable Group By FromProfileId)
```

It Will Show Like This:

```
FromProfileId. | Message  |  DateTime
214            |  "hiii"  |  2013-12-26 10:22
201            |  "brb"   |  2013-12-26 10:15
```

Is this what you want??

Comment: sorry you could't understand the problem.Suppose my user id is 206 so then i have received message from user id 206, then again i did the reply to 214 (above first 2 rows). its a single conversation between 2 user(206 and 214).After that i have received message from user id 200, it's also a conversation, then i send a message to a user id 184 it's also a different conversation. now i have 3 conversations, i want to show all these three conversation with its last message.There will be n number of conversation.For more idea, look Facebook,message list.I have need same as it

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this when searching for user 206:

```
Select Max(MessageId), PartnerId
From
(
    Select MessageId,
        PartnerId = FromProfileId 
    From MessagingTable
    Where ToProfileId = 206
    Union All 
    Select MessageId,
         PartnerId = ToProfileId 
    From MessagingTable 
    Where FromProfileId = 206
) Messages
Group By PartnerId
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your response, i have find the solution for this issue,

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by outerRow)as Row from 
(select * ,Row_Number() over (partition by a.TargetUser order by a.datetime desc)as    
outerRow from
(select *, case when ToProfileID=206 then FromProfileID  when 
FromProfileID=206 then ToProfileID end as TargetUser from Message 
where ToProfileID=206 or FromProfileID=206)a)b where b.outerRow=1
```